# How to extract all available formats for a video, select a particular format and download it using yt-dlp in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, youtube-dl, yt-dlp

I need to pass the YouTube video `url` and need to get all the available download format of that video.
(I'm achieving this using the `ydlp.extract_info(url, download=False)` method.)

Then from the all available formats, I need to filter and select a particular format. for example, I need a video with `resolution=720p`, `video without audio` type and `extension=webm`. (For this, I'm filtering the results of `ydlp.extract_info(url, download=False)` and selecting the particular format)

Now, I need to pass this selected format to a function and download the video. And I also need to pass the output `filepath` & `filename`.
I tried, `ydlp.process_ie_result` method but I'm getting an error while running.

```
import yt_dlp

ydlp = yt_dlp.YoutubeDL()

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d95PPykB2vE'

video_info = ydlp.extract_info(url, download=False)
formats = video_info['formats']

# selecting a random format for now
formats = formats[5]

ydlp.process_ie_result(formats, download=True)
```

But if I run this program, I getting this error,

```
 raise ExtractorError('Missing "id" field in extractor result', ie=info_dict['extractor'])
                                                                      ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'extractor'
```

I'm using `yt-dlp` version `2023.06.22`

In `pytube` we can,

- get all available streams for a video
- filter a selected stream that we need to download and
- download that stream.

Basically I'm trying to achieve this using `yt-dlp`